# Cannot get subviews for a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I add 3 image views in `vwProgress2`, with tag 100, 101, 102 respectively. But, I am getting 0 count when I print its subview..

[image]

```
NSLog(@"%d",[[vwProgress2 subviews]count]);

    for (UIView *subView in vwProgress2.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && subView.tag >= 100) {
            [(UIImageView *)subView setImage:nil];
            NSLog(@"Hello");
        }
    }
```

What can be the reason ? I have set proper `IBOutlet`.

Comment: I am getting 0 count, and "Hello" is not getting printed. Actually the control even not entering the For loop as subview count is 0..

Comment: Please verify that the image views are added in `vwProgress2` or not.

Comment: See, I have attached a screenshot to the question..

Comment: can you share your project via github or dropbox or something?

Comment: @NSPratik: Did you connected the vwProgress2 outlet to the view ?

Comment: Yes..I have crosschecked it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use viewWithTag: method to get image view from tag, try this code,

```
UIImageView *queProgress = (UIImageView *)[self. vwProgress2 viewWithTag: 100];
UIImageView *queTrue = (UIImageView *)[self. vwProgress2 viewWithTag: 101];
UIImageView *queFalse = (UIImageView *)[self. vwProgress2 viewWithTag: 102];
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *queProgress = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag: 100];
UIImageView *queTrue = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag: 101];
UIImageView *queFalse = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag: 102];
```